# Why it is not possible to use IList<T> in interface definition and List<T> in inplementation?

Tags: c#

Why it is not possible to use IList in interface definition and then implement this property using List? Am I missing something here or just C# compiler doesn't allow this?

```
public interface ICategory
{
    IList<Product> Products { get; }
}

public class Category : ICategory
{
    public List<Product> Products { get { new List<Product>(); } }        
}
```

compiler says Error 82 'Category' does not implement interface member 'ICategory.Products'. 'Category.Products' cannot implement 'ICategory.Products' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'

Comment: Interesting Question, this has sth to do with more Covariance and Contravariance support introduced in .Net 4.

Comment: @Marc, @Ludek see my answer dudes, maybe not so smart but I want to show the possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be an **exact** match between the interface's method and the concrete method that *implements* the interface's method. One option is explicit interface implementation, which allows you to satisfy the interface while keeping your more-specific public API on the type. And *usually* just proxy the methods, so there is no code duplication:

```
public interface ICategory
{
    IList<Product> Products { get; }
}

public class Category : ICategory
{
    IList<Product> ICategory.Products { get { return Products ; } }
    public List<Product> Products { get { ...actual implementation... } }        
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Change your code to:

```
public interface ICategory
{
    IList<Product> Products { get; }
}

public class Category : ICategory
{
    // Return IList<Product>, not List<Product>
    public IList<Product> Products { get { new List<Product>(); } }        
}
```

You cannot change the signature of an interface method when you implement it.

Comment: thank you.. I know I can do this. In fact I need to implement property as:  public DbSet<Product> (which is class from EF which implements IList and I used List just as an example). I dont want expose DbSet in iterface definition.. Anyway it seems to me that compiler simply does not allow this covariance/contravariance (can never remeber which one it is :).

Comment: @Ludek: See Marc Gravell's answer where he explains how you can provide an explicit interface implementation to properly implement the interface and still provide your own property having a more specific type.

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
public interface ICategory<out T> where T:IList<Product>
    {
        T Product { get; }
    }

public class Category : ICategory<List<Product>>
    {
        public List<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Although complicated but possible.

Comment: thank you, this should work as well... but it is too much complicated to read for such easy thing :)

Comment: Yes I said that, but I want to show that how this would be possible. :-)